# How to print the value of prestashop global variable in jquery

Tags: prestashop

I want to get prestashop theme folder url in javascript file? I am using prestashop global variable in my javascript file but i get some error:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#click-me-web-service").click(function() {
        var folder_url = "{$tpl_dir}"; // i got problem in this line
  jQuery.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: { first_name: "Joh", last_name: "Sin", username: "johsin", email: "john12@gmail.com" }
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
   alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Always wrap you JS code with `{literal}{/literal}` to avoid conflicts of using `}` in both Smarty and JS.

To insert a smarty variable into a "literalled"? zone, do the opposite:

```
{literal}{$tpl_dir}{literal}
```

This will "temporarily open" the smarty tags and allow you to use Smarty variables.